# Concatenating files with Ansible

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible, how would I go about copying the contents of the example file:

```
/tmp/example.txt

cat example.txt
1234
```

And adding its contents to the below file:

```
/tmp/example2.txt
cat example2.txt
5678
```

So, in the end, example2.txt has the contents of:

```
12345678
```

Comment: What's wrong with `shell: cat /tmp/example.txt /tmp/example2.txt > /tmp/example3.txt && mv /tmp/example3.txt /tmp/example2.txt`? Of course there is a more verbose ansible way of doing it, but what's your **question**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below task will accomplish this:

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: update example2.txt
      lineinfile:
        path: example2.txt
        regexp: "^{{ lookup('file', 'example2.txt') }}"
        line: "{{ lookup('file', 'example.txt') }}{{ lookup('file', 'example2.txt') }}"
```